# Where should I ask questions about web browsers?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where would I ask questions about web browsers? It is not about web design, or development, but about the actual web browser.

Comment: This duplicate suggestion is blatantly incorrect.  In particular, the correct answer, [su], is _not mentioned anywhere on the page_.

Comment: @RyanM Super User is mentioned in several comments. Since Super User is for questions about computer hardware and software, it is an unfortunate omission not to be included. On the other hand, this question doesn't include enough details to argue that it's unrelated to Computer Science / Programming.

Answer (score 15):

Of all the places, most likely [Super User](http://superuser.com), but it would still depend on the nature of your question with regards to that software.

Answer (score 2):

Many things could be asked about [web browsers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_browser). Stack Exchange has many sites where some of those questions might be asked. Please take a look at the complete list of sites at https://stackexchange.com/sites.

You might find it helpful by looking at the *Hot Network Questions* at https://stackexchange.com and the [Real Time view](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=realtime). Another handy tool is the global search, also at https://stackexchange.com.

Type your search query in the text box on the Stack Exchange top bar to use the global search.

[image: Stack Exchange top bar]

You might also find it helpful to learn about **tags**. In Stack Exchange sites, all questions should have at least one tag. Some tags have generic names like `web-browser`. Searching [[web-browser]](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bweb-browser%5D) returns +6k questions and answers. There are also tags named after specific web browsers like Google Chrome. Searching [[google-chrome]](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-chrome%5D) returns 211,138 results.

Please remember that multiple sites have tags with the same name, but each community decides how that tag will be used on their site. Also, different tag names might refer to the same thing; this happens because each community decides how tags should be named.

Anyway, below is a selection of sites where you might ask questions about web browsers:

- As a web browser is a tool commonly used in programming, some questions might be asked in [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com).
- As a web browser is computer software, some questions might be asked in [Super User](https://superuser.com), [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com), and [Computer Science Educators](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com).
- As a web browser might be [Apple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Inc.) software and run on [Apple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Inc.) hardware, some questions might be asked in [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com).
- As a web browser might be an [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) application, some questions might be asked in [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com).
- As a web browser might be run on [Unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix) and [Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux), some questions might be asked in [Unix and Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com).
- As a web browser might be run on [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu), some questions might be asked in [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com).
- As a web browser might be run on [Raspberry Pi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi), some questions might be asked in [Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/).
- As a web browser might be [reverse-engineered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_engineering), some questions might be asked in [Reverse Engineering](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com).
- As a web browser is related to [information technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_technology), some questions might be asked in [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com).
- As there are many web browsers, some questions might be asked in [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com).

But never ask a question that should be addressed to a [customer service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Customer_service) agent.

###### Related

- [Build and strengthen the Stack Exchange community with "crossover questions" between sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199989/1359324)
- [On which Stack Exchange site can I ask customer service questions about product X or company Y?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347991/1359324)
- [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129598/1359324)